# Is there a way to listen silent events on backbonejs?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to listen backbone's model's ´changed´-event for certain attribute, like

```
this.listenTo(this, 'change:someAttr', this.eventListener);
```

However, it is changed silently, so normal event listening does not work. Is there a way to listen backbone's silent events?

Comment: That option is there for a reason. You'll probably need to monkey patch backbone and suppress the option

Comment: Option itself is geat. But it would be nice to be able to manually override it if need rises.

Comment: That means you have to go and override the source code. It doesn't make any sense to provide an option and then another option to suppress the functionality of the previous option. If you don't want the functionality -> don't use it. This use case sounds like you're trying to hack around an already built application. It's not the frameworks job to provide options to hack around - you have to do it yourself...

Comment: Why would you set it silently if you want to trigger an event? The reason for using silent is to avoid event triggering of the event. Please read backbone documentation  - https://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is via some sort of "polling", ie checking over and over via a setInterval.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenSilent();
},
listenSilent: function() {
    var startVal = this.get('myAttr');
    var that = this;
    var silentListener = setInterval(function() {
        if (that.get('myAttr') !== startVal) {
            that.trigger('myevent'); // any custom event name that you can listen to
            stopInterval(silentListener);
            that.listenSilent();
        }
    }, 100);
}
```